# Can we use zookeper as configuration management?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed

I'm working with distributed tools quite some time now. I understand zookeeper and the importance of maintaining the metadata and so.

Would like to know if Zookeeper could be used as a configuration management? I mean I set some key-value pairs like I do in .properties and could be referred from Kafka or Nifi or elsewhere(with in the distributed environment).

In simple terms, could I use zookeeper as key-value pair map? Help me understand.

Comment: Technically it can be done but it would be an overkill to use Zookeeper for just for it see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460901/whats-the-difference-between-zookeeper-and-any-distributed-key-value-stores

Comment: @asolanki i'm not just using zookeeper for key-value pair reference. I've zookeeper configure for kafka/nifi etc... Just wanted to know if zoo could deliver the 'notification mechanism on any of the key-value pair change'?

Answer (score 0):

May be what you need is a [Zookeeper watch](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.3/zookeeperProgrammers.html#ch_zkWatches).

A watch is mechanism for sending notification to the Zookeeper client when a change happens on the value of a ZNode.

To simplify the implementation, you can use one of the Curator recipes to get notification on value change/deletion of a Zookeeper node see example [here](https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/node-cache.html)